# fusebox dev server with /api route

Tags: fusebox

I'm trying to configure fusebox so that it serves my app in root but also an API (for testing only) with /api.

With webpack I managed to get this with the following

```
devServer: {
    setup: function (app) {
      app.use('/api', jsonServer.router('db.json'));
    }
  }
```

so when I get to http://localhost:8080 I get my app index.html, but when I type http://localhost:8080/api I get the contents of db.json, so I can mock an API Rest that returns json data.

In fusebox I'm using this:

```
fuse.dev(server => {
  const app = server.httpServer.app;
  app.use('/api', jsonServer.router('db.json'));
});
```

and my app is being served in http://localhost:4444, but when I try http://localhost:4444/api, there's nothing.
I tried this:

```
fuse.dev({ root: false }, server => {
  const app = server.httpServer.app;
  app.use('/api', jsonServer.router('db.json'));
});
```

And then the API works in http://localhost:4444/api, but then I can´t get to http://localhost:4444, so I can´t load my app.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

It seems that when a new route is defined you HAVE to also define the root. So this will do:

```
fuse.dev({ root: 'dist' }, server => {
  const app = server.httpServer.app;
  app.use('/api', jsonServer.router('db.json'));
});
```